# Customize preference theme

Tags: android, android-theme, android-preferences

I am currently trying to customize color of the preference section. But I don't know how to do that.

In my app I have two themes: Dark Theme And Light Theme. It is an option that the user chooses. In my main activity I set the theme chosen by the user.

And after I use attr to define which color to display.

But in my preference fragment I don't know how to proceed. I read that I have to create new style, in other thread, the solution is to create my custom listPreference... What is the best way to do that?

here the dark theme:
[image: dark theme]

for example, "year formation" and "group" are disabled so I want to show it (change color of disabled fields)

current listPreference:

[image: current list preference]
Here I want a dark background.

CODE:
style.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- theme clair  -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

        <!-- Color -->
        <item name="colorAppBarAndDrawer">@color/colorAppBarAndDrawerLight</item>
        <item name="colorBackground">@color/colorBackgroundLight</item>
        <item name="colorText">@color/colorTextLight</item>
        <item name="colorTextSecondary">@color/colorTextSecondaryLight</item>
        <item name="colorItem">@color/colorItemLight</item>

        <!-- images -->
        <item name="iconRefresh">@drawable/ic_refresh_black_24dp</item>
        <item name="iconFirstPage">@drawable/ic_first_page_black_24dp</item>
        <item name="iconSchedule">@drawable/ic_schedule_black_24dp</item>

        <!-- menu -->
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/colorTextLight</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorTextSecondaryLight</item>

        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorTextLight</item>

      

    </style>

    <!-- theme sombre -->
    <style name="AppThemeNight" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

        <item name="colorAppBarAndDrawer">@color/colorAppBarAndDrawerDark</item>
        <item name="colorBackground">@color/colorBackgroundDark</item>
        <item name="colorText">@color/colorTextDark</item>
        <item name="colorItem">@color/colorItemDark</item>
        <item name="colorTextSecondary">@color/colorTextSecondaryDark</item>


        <!-- images -->
        <item name="iconRefresh">@drawable/ic_refresh_white_24dp</item>
        <item name="iconFirstPage">@drawable/ic_first_page_white_24dp</item>
        <item name="iconSchedule">@drawable/ic_schedule_white_24dp</item>

        <!-- menu -->
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/colorTextDark</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorTextSecondaryDark</item>

        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorTextDark</item>
      

    </style>

    <style name="PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14" parent="@style/PreferenceFixTheme.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!--<item name="android:background">?attr/colorAppBarAndDrawer</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?attr/colorText</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">?attr/colorTextSecondary</item>-->

    <item name="colorAccent">#1976D2</item>

    </style>



    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />


</resources>
```

Like I said, I have tried solution. What I have to do?

Thanks a lot

**EDIT**
I changed preferenceActivity to preferenceActivityCompat,  now I can change color of switch buttons.  in style.xml I added this:

```
<style name="PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14" parent="@style/PreferenceFixTheme.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!--<item name="android:background">?attr/colorAppBarAndDrawer</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">?attr/colorText</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">?attr/colorTextSecondary</item>-->

        <item name="colorAccent">#1976D2</item>

    </style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did'nt find real solution. I used the theme editor in Android Studio and chose colors with the color picker. Now it works. I dont know if I should make this post as "solved" ?
Thanks
Thomas